# Minecraft Launcher Update

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

My Minecraft launcher won't update whatever I do. I have downloaded the new launcher file, still same version. I have clicked edit profile, but the only versions there are are 1.6.2 and "use latest version". still staying in 1.6.2. It used to update normally and well but now it's stuck in the launcher version 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to delete your `.minecraft` folder.
On windows you'd press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `%appdata%`. Now copy the `saves` folder in the `.minecraft` folder to a save place, and delete the whole `.minecraft` folder.
Then download the launcher again and see if it works.